# Logical Error with PHP! A password length check

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, logic

I am getting a logical error I believe I am using PHP as my server side language and I am performing password checks. Users will not be allowed to enter a password less than 8 characters and no more than 32 characters.

register.php

```
<?php $pageTitle = "Register"; ?>
<?php $sectoin = "signing"; ?>

<?php include 'INC/header.php'; ?>

    <?php

            $submit         = $_POST['submit'];
            $username       = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
            $password       = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
            $repeatPassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatPassword']);
            $email          = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
            $date           = date("m-d-Y");

            if ($submit) {

                // Checking for exsistence
                if ($username && $password && repeatPassword && $email) {

                    // Encrypts the Pasword
                    $password = md5($password);
                    $repeatPassword = md5($repeatPassword);

                    // Do Passwords Match
                    if ($password == $repeatPassword) {

                        // Check Character Length of Username
                        if (strlen($username) > 16 || strlen($username) <= 2) {

                          echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Your <b>Username</b> must be between 3 and 16 characters! </h3> </span>";  

                        } else {

                            // Check Password Length
                            if (strlen($password && $repeatPassword) < 8) {

                                echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Your <b>Password</b> is less than 8 characters! </h3> </span>";

                            } else {

                                echo 'Registration Completed!';

                            }

                        }

                    } else echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-danger'> Your <b>Passwords</b> must match! </h3> </span>";

                } else echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Please fill out <b>All</b> fields!</h3> </span>";

            }

        ?>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="page-header">

                            <h3 class="text-center"> Registration </h3>

                        </div>

                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="register.php" method="POST">

                            <!--Start of Username-->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Username </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span> </span>

                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" />

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--End of Username-->

                            <!--Start of E-Mail-->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> E-Mail </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </span> </span>

                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" />

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--End of E-Mail-->

                            <!--Start of Password-->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Password </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </span> </span>

                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--End of Password-->

                            <!--Start of Repeat Password-->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="repeatPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> <span id="repeatPassword"> Repeat Password </span> </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <div class="input-group">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"> </span> </span>

                                        <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            <!--End of Repeat Password-->

                            <!--Start of Checkbox and Submit Button-->
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                                    <label class="checkbox"> 

                                        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="rememberMe" id="rememberMe"> <span id="rememberUs"> Remember Me </span>

                                    </label>

                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary slideToTheLeft"> Register </button>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

        </div>

    <?php include 'INC/footer.php'; ?>
```

If I take the '&& $repeatPassword' out of the equation it skips the condition and echos.

```
if (strlen($password && $repeatPassword) < 8 {
```

However, it is called that $repeatPassword = $password, so I shouldn't even need the '&& repeatPassword' but it won't do anything if it is included into the code.

However, the main problem besides that is that no matter what the if statement is stating that no matter what the password is less than 8 characters.

Comment: `if( strlen( $password ) < 8 or strlen( $repeatpassword ) < 8 )` ?

Comment: Nope, still giving my error.

Comment: Is this just a typo? `if ($username && $password && repeatPassword && $email) {` ?? the `repeatpassword` is not valid by the looks of things. Perhaps more like `if ($username && $password && $repeatPassword && $email) {`

Comment: No that is validating if the user has entered the following the fields: username, password, repeat password, and E-Mail. Sorry, yes that was meant to be capitalized.

Comment: it's missing the `$` from the variable `repeatPassword `

Comment: Good catch! However, its still calling my warning message.

Answer (score 0):

As a means of testing if supplied values are within permitted bounds you could try:

```
$valid_username=in_array( strlen( $username ), range(2,16) );
$valid_password=$password===$repeatPassword && in_array( strlen( $password ), range(8,32) );


if( $valid_username && $valid_password ){/* all good */}
```

example:

```
if( $submit ) {
    if( $username && $password && $repeatPassword && $email ) {

        // hash the Passwords
        $password = md5( trim( $password ) );
        $repeatPassword = md5( trim( $repeatPassword ) );

        $unrange=range(3,16);
        $pwdrange=range(8,32);

        $valid = true;
        $valid_username = in_array( strlen( $username ), $unrange );
        $valid_password = in_array( strlen( $password ), $pwdrange );
        $password_match = $password===$repeatPassword;


        if( !$valid_password ){
            $valid=false;
            echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Your <b>Password</b> should be between ".min( $pwdrange )." and ".max( $pwdrange )." characters! </h3> </span>";
        }

        if( !$valid_username ){
            $valid=false;
            echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Your <b>Username</b> must be between ".min( $unrange )." and ".max( $unrange )." characters! </h3> </span>";
        }

        if( !$password_match ){
            $valid=false;
            echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-danger'> Your <b>Passwords</b> must match! </h3> </span>";
        }

        if( $valid ) {
            echo 'Registration Completed!';
            /* add to db? */
        }

    } else echo "<h3 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Please fill out <b>All</b> fields!</h3> </span>";
}
```

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: Alright, so I'm getting the majority of this code. However, just to clarify 'unrange = range(3,6);' This is the user name and below the password? Then would I leave $submit         = $_POST['submit'];
        $username       = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password       = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        $repeatPassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatPassword']);
        $email          = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
        $date           = date("m-d-Y"); that code in?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to check the length  of both $password and $repeatPassword since you will also be checking to see if they match each other.

```
if (strlen($password < 8) {
    // error
} elseif ($password != $repeatPassword) {
    // error
} else {
    // ALL IS GOOD !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had actually solved my problem, I decided to take out the or to the password and it had solved the problem and everything is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (strlen($password) >= 8 && strlen($password) <= 32) {
 if (strlen($repeatpassword) >= 8 && strlen($repeatpassword) <= 32) {
  // code here
 }
}
```

I think it's a bit odd to check both passwords, however.

So, my solution would be:

```
if (strlen($password) >= 8  && strlen($password) <= 32) {
 // code here
}
```